# Trying to position a div in the center when a text in it is too long

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this div for showing notifications:

```
// css
    #my_div {
        min-width: 250px;
        margin-left: -125px;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 50%;
    }


// html

<div id="my_div">some text</div>
```

It looks fine only when a text in it is relatively short, around 10-15 characters.

When text is longer than that, it won't look great because its left conner **still remains in the center of the screen** while its right conner goes  all the way to the right coner to fit the text.

I've found out that that has to do with "margin-left" and "left" somehow, they should be adjusted.

How to do that in a proper fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `margin: auto`.
You may want to add a maximum width to `#my_div` as well - i.e. `max-width:500px`, otherwise the notification box will fill the fullwidth of the window.

```css
   #my_div {
        min-width: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
        background: yellow;
    }
    
    .wrap {
      text-align:center;
      background: grey;
      width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div id="my_div">some text</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left: 0 auto;` ---> invalid property value